# android tabwidget custom

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i have this custom tab widget..
before i've customized it, by default i have a custom delimiter between each tab..

is there a way to make it still visible although i have a custom backgruond ?

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/footer_overbg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/footer_overbg" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/footer_overbg" android:state_selected="true"/>    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/footer_bg"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Show us your custom tabwidget.

Comment: This is xml file which set the custon drawable of the background..

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need. I think, [Maybe you're expecting like this](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what i am thinking is correct then you need this

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.divider_vertical_dark);
```

it seems you want a divider between each tab.